# RadioButton not selected tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I've been learning tkinter and I ran into this thing I don't understand, what does it mean when a radio button has a '-'? it's like is neither marked nor unmarked, is it not returning anything?

I grabbed this code from the internet so anyone can see what I mean:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
btn1 = StringVar()


def do_something():
    val0 = entry1.get()
    val1 = btn1.get()
    print("The variable values are " + val1 + " and " + val0)
    print("The method values are " + btn1.get() + " and " + entry1.get())


rb1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Euro", value="euro",
              variable=btn1).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
rb2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Dollar", value="dollar",
              variable=btn1).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
rb3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Yen", value="yen",
              variable=btn1).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
label1 = Label(root, text="Input Here")
label1.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

go = Button(root, text="Print Selection", fg="white",
            bg="black", command=do_something)
go.grid(row=10, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

This happened to me in a class as well, a group of radio buttons have this hyphen in them until I bound self to the StringVar(), what's happening under the hood?

Comment: You need to initialize `btn1` to something other than empty string or `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IntVar()` instead of `StringVar()`. In Python 3.8+ Used **f-string format**.

Here is code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
btn1 = IntVar()


def do_something():
    val0 = float(entry1.get())
    val1 = val0
    print(f"The variable values are {val1}  and {val0}")
    print(f"The method values are {val1} and {val0}")


rb1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Euro", value="euro",
              variable=btn1).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

rb2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Dollar", value="dollar",
              variable=btn1).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

rb3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Yen", value="yen",
              variable=btn1).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)

label1 = Label(root, text="Input Here")
label1.grid(row=1, sticky=E)

entry1 = Entry(root)
entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

go = Button(root, text="Print Selection", fg="white",
            bg="black", command=do_something)
go.grid(row=10, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Result before:

[image]

Result after:

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you want to print in widget instead of debug.

Comment: Ok, thank you for answering, what if I want to print the selection? Because of the way you did it, it throws a Tcl error.

Comment: How come you suggest using `IntVar` when those `value` options of radiobuttons are strings?

Comment: @acw1668 Hey man I found the answer to my actual question in another question you answered here in stack overflow, like I said, I was having this problem in a class as well. You said we have to bind self to the variable because the garbage collector takes it after the function is completed. Thanks!